# Exception (403) Reason: "username or password not allowed"

Tags: docker, go, ssl, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I am trying to access rabbitmq cluster where TLS is enabled. I have written sample go app which trying to connect to the rabbitmq server using set of client certificates and client keys.

I am facing error -

```
Error is - Exception (403) Reason: "username or password not allowed"
panic: Exception (403) Reason: "username or password not allowed"
```

My code snippet

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go RabbitMQ Consumer Tutorial")
    fmt.Println("Testing ClusterIP service connection over TLS")

    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("client.crt", "client.key")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //Load CA cert.
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ca.crt") // The same you configured in your MQ server
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    TlsConfig1 := &tls.Config{
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert}, // from tls.LoadX509KeyPair
        RootCAs:            caCertPool,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        // ...other options are just the same as yours
    }
    
    conn, err := amqp.DialTLS("amqps://<username>:<password>@<rabbitmq-service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:5671/", TlsConfig1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error is -", err)
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to consumer successfully")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer ch.Close()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        "TestQueue",
        "",
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )

    forever := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            fmt.Printf("Recieved Message: %s\n", d.Body)
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("Successfully Connected to our RabbitMQ Instance")
    fmt.Println(" [*] - Waiting for messages")
    <-forever

}
```

The code snippet is running as pod in the EKS cluster where my rabbitmq cluster is running.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the rabbitmq TLS debugging doc- https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html I figured out that I was giving wrong username and password.

NOTE: if any one who is also getting the same error - please confirm that you are using correct username and password.

You can check the username and password for the cluster by logging into the rabbitmq cluster pod.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me on version 11.6.0 but not on 10.3.9.